# How i can download image from multiple url in a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, url, jupyter-notebook, wget

How can i download all image from multiple urls in a list in a pandas dataframe. I am a python newbie.

```
# for a single url, i can download the image:

url = ['http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EPFVkqcWkAYTDVi.jpg'] 

import wget
for photos in url:
    wget.download(photos)

# But i have multiple url in the list. 

url = ['http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EPFVkqcWkAYTDVi.jpg,http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EPFVkqcWkAYTDVi.jpg,http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EPFVkqcWkAYTDVi.jpg'] 

# i get error trying to download all the images
**Exception: 404: Not Found**

# I also want the download to skip any invalid url and continue.
```

Comment: you have to split string into a list.
`url = url[0].split(',')`

Comment: Quote each URL separately so each URL is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Quote each url separately and use Try\Except for errors:

Try this code:

```
url = ['https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/pier_sea_horizon_189419_168x300.jpg',
       'https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/paint_liquid_fluid_art_189413_168x300.jpg',
       'https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/sunset_glare_city_189428_168x300.jpg',
       'https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/maple_leaf_macro_189405_168x300.jpg']
        
import wget
import time  # for sleep

for photos in url:
    try: 
       print('\nGet:', photos)   
       wget.download(photos)
       time.sleep(1)  # pause 1 second, if needed
    except Exception as ex:
       print('Failed to get:',photos, ex)
```

Output

```
Get: https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/pier_sea_horizon_189419_168x300.jpg
100% [................................................................................] 7216 / 7216
Get: https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/paint_liquid_fluid_art_189413_168x300.jpg
100% [..............................................................................] 10146 / 10146
Get: https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/sunset_glare_city_189428_168x300.jpg
100% [................................................................................] 7412 / 7412
Get: https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/maple_leaf_macro_189405_168x300.jpg
100% [..............................................................................] 12837 / 12837
```

Comment: @Mike64, the code seems to work and the exception also work. But the code only downloaded two out of the three images. How can i modify it to download all three images? Even when i used four urls, only two images were downloaded. Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer with 4 images. They all downloaded correctly. If you have issues downloading, you can add `sleep` in the loop or add logic to retry the download,

Comment: Yes it downloaded all with sleep in the loop. Thanks